# Codeigniter Resize function not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

Hi friends I am trying to use codeigniters resize image_lib .. and I am not able to resize the image using this one. Please help me to solve this issue

**Error:**

**using gd:**
The path to the image is not correct.Your server does not support the GD function required to process this type of image.

**using ImageMagick:**
The path to the image is not correct.The path to your image library is not correct. Please set the correct path in your image preferences.

**Code:**

```
            $this->load->library('upload');

            $config['upload_path'] = $path;

            $config['file_name']  = $file_name;

            $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|png'; 

            $config['overwrite'] = false;

            $this->upload->initialize($config);

            if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
            {    
                    return false;
            }    

            else{
                    $this->load->library('image_lib');

                    $resize['image_library'] = 'gd2';
                    $resize['source_image'] = $path.$file_name;    

                    $resize['maintain_ratio'] = FALSE;
                    $resize['width'] = 40; 
                    $resize['height'] = 40; 
                    $resize['quality'] = 100;

          //           print_r($path.$file_name);
         // Here the path of the image is assets/Data/adv_images/2/2-537f2a3651300
        //  which is absolutely right  also tried base_url().$path.$file_name

                    $this->image_lib->initialize($resize);

                    if ( ! $this->image_lib->resize()){
                            echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();
                            }   
                    return true;
            }
```

Comment: can you try `ImageMagick` instead of GD2 and post results.

Comment: @karanthakkar I have edited the post and added results of Imagemagick to the post although the path of the image is right

Comment: can you show us the $path variable

Comment: $path = 'assets/Data/adv_images/2/' and $file_name = '2-537f2a3651300' . Do i need to change the file permissions while uploading it ?

Comment: it should be `$path = './assets/Data/adv_images/2/'` @HackerRocker

Comment: ./assets/Data/adv_images/2/2-537f3009a0205 is also not working :/The Image is being uploaded. But the problem is with image resize

Comment: are you sure the file exist `2-537f3009a0205` and where is its extension ? `.jpg or .png` something like that if its an image. @HackerRocker

Comment: using $config['file_name'] I have modified the file name and reg the path I am able to view the image in my browser given the path as the url (adding base_url() to it)

Comment: @www.sblog.in perhaps you should write a less verbose answer so whenever sblog.in will go down, answer is still avalible..

Answer (score 0):

try to set path by this way:

`$resize['source_image'] = $this->upload->data()['full_path'];`